# cronjob path is wrong for cake3 project

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp3 I cannot get my cronjob to run as I keep getting
 /bin/bash: bin/cake: No such file or directory from the email feedback I set in my cpanel

The file is in the folder called Shell in the project and the file name is called invoicingShell.php

The folder of bin is in the cakephp3 project where it should be and I am using a linux OS. What am I doing wrong?

My cronjob is set in cronjobs Cpanel (every min for testing)
i omitted the real account name below

```
cd /home/myaccount/public_html/crm/src && bin/cake invoicing postpaid
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the `bin/cake` part? For example: `/path/to/bin/cake`?

Comment: First, you should try to run the command manually on console. Then you should see if something's wrong.

Comment: cd /home/xx/public_html/crm/src && /home/xx/public_html/crm/bin/cake invoicing postpaid   no  good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed your application structure somehow, because in official CakePHP Skeleton app, directory structure is like

```
ROOT
├───bin
     └───cake
     └───cake.bat
     └───cake.php
├───config
├───logs
├───plugins
├───src
├───tests
├───tmp
├───vendor
├───webroot
```

See https://github.com/cakephp/app

Answer (score 0):

You are try to run cake command in src folder. It should be outside of src folder. You need to remove src in command path.

```
cd /home/myaccount/public_html/crm && bin/cake invoicing postpaid
```

Comment: can you show me please with an example as I tried removing the src folder ans the shell folder is in the src folder isnt it? And you can run functions from the controller so I think your answer is wrong

Comment: @jagguy `bin/cake` is not inside the src folder. check here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html

Comment: Please try to run your command using command line by login as root in your server of your local machine.